# Apply a view to every folder in evolution

Tags: evolution

How can I make evolution display every folder the same way, with the same columns and -widths and no preview field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it automatically, but what you can do is the following :

- set your view to your liking in your inbox
- click Views > Current view > Save custom view
- give your custom view a name and save
- click on another folder and go to View > Current view > your custom view

You have to do this for all the folders you want your custom view applied.

PS: I hope the translation is correct, my system is in French.

Comment: My system is German, so I cannot confirm the translation :)

Comment: So long as it works mein freund :)